# How to generate dictionary for categorical values

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, data-cleaning

i have a pandas data frame fiend like below

```
df.wlan_mgt_fixed_reason_code.unique()
= array(['?', '0x0002', '0x0003', ..., '0x0c3c', '0xbf17', '0x4cee'], dtype=object)
```

I need to replace these unique values with unique numbers as I want to run the data through an ANN.

I need to make a dictionary out of the unique values so that I can replace them in the below manner.

```
di = 
{
 "0x0002" : 2, 
 "0x0003" : 3, 
 "0x0001" : 4, 
 "0x0006" : 5, 
 "0x0007" : 6, 
 "0x0008" : 7, 
 "0x944f" : 8, 
 "0xda64" : 9, 
 "0x7415" : 10, 
 "0x64d7" : 11, 
 "0x130d" : 12, 
 "0x39a1" : 13, 
 "0x5df0" : 14, 
 "0xc87e" : 15, 
 "0x744f" : 16, 
 "0x7983" : 17, 
 "0x0632" : 18, 
 "0x3922" : 19, 
 "0x2c60" : 20, 
 "0xa5d9" : 21, 
 "0x02b8" : 22, 
 "0x71c4" : 23, 
 "0x0c3c" : 24, 
 "0xbf17" : 25, 
 "0x4cee" : 1, 
}
```

And then replace on the column with the dictionary values.

Is there a simple way to automate this, or maybe a code snippet that  automatically identifies the unique categorical values and replaces them with sequential numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Try [`categorical`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html):

```
df.wlan_mgt_fixed_reason_code = df.wlan_mgt_fixed_reason_code.astype('category')
```

**THAT SAID** the data type is still pretty new, meaning that you might want to stick with a standard vectorizer:

```
uniqs = list(df.wlan_mgt_fixed_reason_code.unique())
uniq_dict = {uniqs[x]: x for x in range(len(uniqs))}
df.wlan_mgt_fixed_reason_code = df.wlan_mgt_fixed_reason_code.replace(uniq_dict)
```